# fullcalendar: set color of individual events using a JSON feed

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display events from a JSON feed in different colors, but they all appear in the same default color. is there a way of setting the event objects color property using JSON? Is there a list of which of the [event object properties](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) are available to JSON?

fullcalendar code:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
              },
      events: '/events/feed',
  });
```

output of json feed:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Green Event",
        "start": "2014-05-05 09:00:00",
        "end": "2014-05-05 17:00:00",
        "allDay": true,
        "color": "00FF00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Red Event",
        "start": "2014-05-06 09:00:00",
        "end": "2014-05-06 17:00:00",
        "allDay": true,
        "color": "FF0000"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `#` before color, replace `"color": "FF0000"` with `color: '#00FF00'` and try

Answer (score 2):

These are color attributes you can use in the latest version of fullCalendar:

eventColor

eventBackgroundColor

eventBorderColor

eventTextColor

also you should use '#' for example:

`{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Green Event",
        "start": "2014-05-05 09:00:00",
        "end": "2014-05-05 17:00:00",
        "allDay": true,
        "eventColor": "#FF0000"
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the className property of the event object, where you may set a css class for each event.

Answer (score 0):

The approach which worked for me used the attribute "color" and used the "#" before the hex digits. For example, the following displays with a red background:

```
color: "#FF0000"
id: "aa49c82f33dc6"
start: "2013-04-21T07:00:00Z"
status: "COMPLETED"
title: "This is the Event Title"
unix_start: 1366527600
```